# Testing a simple service with $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I have a simple service that I want to test. I'm using $httpBackend to mock requests. I'm having problems getting the mocked data back after the ajax call. I know its asynchronous. I need a simple way to return the mocked data back.

```
angular.module('adminApp').service("categoryService", function ($http) {

    this.getAllCategories = function () {
        console.log("GOING TO CALL GET"); 
        $http.get("./category/categories").success(function(data, status, headers){
            console.log("IN SUCCESS", data); // the right data is displayed but not returned to the test
             // i need to do something here to return the data to my test
            return data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("ERROR: ", data,status,headers,config);
        });

    };
});
```

The test

```
describe("Category Service Tests", function () {

    var myCategoryService, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module("adminApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function (categoryService,_$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.when("GET", "./category/categories").respond(["hello","world"]);
        myCategoryService = categoryService;
     }));

     afterEach(function() {
         $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
         $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
     });

     it('should not be undefined', function() {
         expect($httpBackend).toBeDefined();
     });

     it("Should not be null", function () {
         expect(myCategoryService).toBeDefined();
     });

     it("Should return all available categories", function () {
         $httpBackend.expect("GET",'./category/categories');
         var categoriesList = myCategoryService.getAllCategories();
         $httpBackend.flush();
         console.log(categoriesList);

         expect(categoriesList.length).toBe(2);
});


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already has problems, it will fail in tests for sure. The problem with your code is you return data **immediately** after an asynch function, at that time the `dataToSend` **is not updated** yet.

Try updating your code like this:

```
app.service("categoryService", function ($http) {

    this.getAllCategories = function (callback) {

        $http.get("./category/categories").success(function(data, status, headers){
            callback(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("ERROR: ", data,status,headers,config);
        });
    };
});
```

Your tests:

```
it("Should return all available categories", function () {
         $httpBackend.expect("GET",'./category/categories');
         var categoriesList;
         myCategoryService.getAllCategories(function(data){
            categoriesList = data;
         });
         $httpBackend.flush();
         console.log(categoriesList);

         expect(categoriesList.length).toBe(2);
   });
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ntLR5FONsY09QWU73Nmt?p=preview)